# Cannot resolve method getIdlingResource() - Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to use IdlingResources to test something after a network call is done. I have a `CountingIdlingResource` keeping track of running jobs in my Main Activity, but my Test file doesn't recognize `getIdlingResource`:

[image]

Here are my import statements:

```
package com.example.android.bakingapp;

import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso;
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import com.example.android.bakingapp.activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.android.bakingapp.activities.RecipeActivity;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
```

I also have this included in my gradle dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'
```

Comment: Does `MainActivity`, in fact, actually have a method called `getIdlingResource()` that returns an idling resource?

Comment: No, I should have realized that MainActivity would need a method like that. But how would that work with the CountingIdlingResource?

Comment: That's totally dependent on your implementation. But, in short, you'd have a counting idling resource in MainActivity that you increment and decrement as needed within the activity, then provide it via the public accessor you thought you had already.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the accessor method and it's working now.

Answer (score 6):

Did you add this dependency to gradle?

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'

Comment: Yes, I have both of those included in my dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to create *getIdlingResource()* method in your MainActivity:

```
@Nullable
private SimpleIdlingResource mIdlingResource;

@VisibleForTesting
@NonNull
public IdlingResource getIdlingResource() {
    if (mIdlingResource == null) {
        mIdlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();
    }
    return mIdlingResource;
}
```

and then create an Idle Resource class:

```
public class SimpleIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    @Nullable private volatile ResourceCallback mCallback;

    private AtomicBoolean mIsIdleNow = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        return mIsIdleNow.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public void setIdleState(boolean isIdleNow) {
        mIsIdleNow.set(isIdleNow);
        if (isIdleNow && mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add that method inside your Activity class. Here is an example project from google sample.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample